# Issue with user defined key in Hadoop Mapreduce

Tags: java, hadoop, mapreduce

I have a NewYork stock exchange Dataset in Tab separated format and my data looks something like this

```
exchange    stock_symbol    date    stock_price_open    stock_price_high stock_price_low        stock_price_close   stock_volume    stock_price_adj_close
NYSE    ASP 2001-12-31  12.55   12.8    12.42   12.8    11300   6.91
NYSE    ASP 2001-12-28  12.5    12.55   12.42   12.55   4800    6.78
NYSE    KEN 2001-12-27  12.59   12.59   12.5    12.57   5400    6.79
NYSE    JPG 2001-12-26  12.45   12.6    12.45   12.55   5400    6.78
NYSE    KEN 2001-12-24  12.61   12.61   12.61   12.61   1400    6.76
NYSE    JPG 2001-12-21  12.4    12.78   12.4    12.6    18200   6.75
```

I need to find the average of open price, high price , low price and close price for a particular symbol for a particular month ie i want my output to be something like this

```
NYSE,ASP,DECEMBER 12.525,12.675,12.42,12.675
NYSE,KEN,DECEMBER 12.60,12.60,12.55,12.58
NYSE,JPG,DECEMBER 12.425,12.69,12.425,12.575
```

In order to do this i used a user defined key which takes exchange,symbol and date as a key

```
    import java.io.DataInput;
import java.io.DataOutput;
import java.io.IOException;

import org.apache.hadoop.io.WritableComparable;


public class ComplexKey implements WritableComparable<ComplexKey>{

    public String exchange;
    public String symbol;
    public String month;
    public ComplexKey() {
        // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
    }

    public ComplexKey(String string, String string2, String string3) {
        this.exchange=string;
        this.symbol=string2;
        this.month=string3;
    }

    @Override
    public void readFields(DataInput arg0) throws IOException {
      this.exchange=arg0.readUTF();
      this.symbol=arg0.readUTF();
      this.month=arg0.readUTF();

    }

    @Override
    public void write(DataOutput arg0) throws IOException {
        arg0.writeUTF(exchange);
        arg0.writeUTF(symbol);
        arg0.writeUTF(month);

    }

@Override
public int compareTo(ComplexKey o) {
    return this.toString().compareTo(o.toString());

}
    public String getExchange() {
        return exchange;
    }
    public String getMonth() {
        return month;
    }
    public String getSymbol() {
        return symbol;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    return this.exchange+","+this.symbol+","+this.month;
    }
    @Override
    public int hashCode() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    return this.exchange.length()*3+this.symbol.length()*2+this.month.hashCode()*9;
    }
    @Override
    public boolean equals(Object obj) {
        if (obj == this) {
            return true;
        }
        if (obj == null || obj.getClass() != this.getClass()) {
            return false;
        }
        ComplexKey k=(ComplexKey)obj;
        return exchange == k.exchange
                && (month == k.month 
                     || (month != null && month.equals(k.getMonth())))
                && (symbol == k.symbol 
                     || (symbol != null && symbol .equals(k.getSymbol())));




    }



}
```

I have a user defined value which is something like

```
import java.io.DataInput;
import java.io.DataOutput;
import java.io.IOException;

import org.apache.hadoop.io.Writable;


public class ComplexValue implements Writable {
public double openPrice;
public double highPrice;
public double lowPrice;
public double closePrice;
public ComplexValue() {
// TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
}
public ComplexValue(double parseDouble, double parseDouble2,
    double parseDouble3, double parseDouble4) {
this.openPrice=parseDouble;
this.highPrice=parseDouble2;
this.lowPrice=parseDouble3;
this.closePrice=parseDouble4;
}

@Override
public void readFields(DataInput arg0) throws IOException {
this.openPrice=arg0.readDouble();
this.highPrice=arg0.readDouble();
this.lowPrice=arg0.readDouble();
this.closePrice=arg0.readDouble();

}

@Override
public void write(DataOutput arg0) throws IOException {
    arg0.writeDouble(openPrice);
    arg0.writeDouble(highPrice);
    arg0.writeDouble(lowPrice);
    arg0.writeDouble(closePrice);

}
public double getOpenPrice() {
    return this.openPrice;
}
public double getClosePrice() {
    return this.closePrice;
}
public double getHighPrice() {
    return this.highPrice;
}
public double getLowPrice() {
    return this.lowPrice;
}

}
```

My mapper takes longwritable as input key, Text as input value and outputs complex key and complex value

```
import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.HashMap;

import org.apache.hadoop.io.LongWritable;
import org.apache.hadoop.io.Text;
import org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.Mapper;


public class StockMapper extends Mapper<LongWritable, Text, ComplexKey, ComplexValue>{
    HashMap<Integer, String>month=new HashMap<Integer, String>();
    @Override
    protected void setup(Context context)
            throws IOException, InterruptedException {
        month.put(1, "January");
        month.put(2, "February");
        month.put(3, "March");
        month.put(4, "April");
        month.put(5, "May");
        month.put(6, "June");
        month.put(7, "July");
        month.put(8, "August");
        month.put(9, "September");
        month.put(10, "October");
        month.put(11, "November");
        month.put(12, "December");



    }
    @Override
    protected void map(LongWritable key, Text value,Context context)
            throws IOException, InterruptedException {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        String []val=value.toString().split("\t");
        if(isNumber(val[3])==true){
            context.write(new ComplexKey(val[0],val[1],month.get(Integer.parseInt(val[2].split("-")[1]))),new ComplexValue(Double.parseDouble(val[3]),Double.parseDouble(val[4]),Double.parseDouble(val[5]),Double.parseDouble(val[6])));
        }

    }
    public boolean isNumber(String n) {

        try{
            double i=Double.parseDouble(n);

        }
        catch(NumberFormatException e){
            return false;
        }
        return true;

    }

}
```

And in reducer i find the average using reduce function

```
import java.io.IOException;

import org.apache.hadoop.io.Text;
import org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.Reducer;


public class StockReducer extends Reducer<ComplexKey, ComplexValue, Text, Text>{
    @Override
    protected void reduce(ComplexKey key, Iterable<ComplexValue> value,Context context)
            throws IOException, InterruptedException {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        double highPrice = 0;
        double lowPrice = 0;
        double openPrice = 0;
        double closePrice = 0;
        int count=0;
        for (ComplexValue i:value){
            ++count;
            highPrice+=i.getHighPrice();
            lowPrice+=i.getLowPrice();
            openPrice+=i.getOpenPrice();
            closePrice+=i.getClosePrice();

        }
        context.write(new Text(key.toString()), new Text(openPrice/count+","+closePrice/count+","+highPrice/count+","+lowPrice/count+","+count));
    }

}
```

Instead of getting the desired output iam getting unaggregated output. I think the issue is with the keys as mapper is unable to differenciate the keys properly. Can anyone explain what is the error in the code?

Comment: In ComplexKey method "equals" is not overriden.

Comment: tried it. Still not working. I omitted that part in the code by mistake here